# Django mysql client

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to install python mysql client via
`pip install mysqlclient`.
but i am getting error like this

```
Command "c:\users\hardik\envs\py1\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hardik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dsz2ubnd\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\hardik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q472cwk5\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\hardik\envs\py1\include\site\python3.7\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hardik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dsz2ubnd\mysqlclient\
```

what should i do to solve it?

Comment: it says failed to building wheels for client

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.7 currently does not support mysqlclient. so do the following

> first, check your python version.

1. Open command prompt or use window+R and type this

   `python --version`
2. After confirming your version, if its 3.7**, Then uninstall python 3.7
3. Go to python website to download python 3.6.* https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-367/
4. After installing the new python version, Then do the following to install your mysqlclient.

Open command prompt as an administrator, then try install again using

> **pip install mysqlclient==1.3.12**

Then restart your IDE (Pycharm or the likes) for it to reflect
i hope this helps

Comment: it says failed to building wheels for client

Comment: If your are using python 3.7 it won't work because it does not support mysqlclient at the moment. Check my updated answer again

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Especially the second one.

Also, what os are you on? If you're on linux make sure to be on a virtual environment while installing any python packages.

Comment: what in windows operating system?

Comment: shouldn't be a problem in windows os. The problem in linux arises due to the fact that some linux distros (e.g. Ubuntu/Debian, I haven't used any non-Debian distro) have Python built in, and doing python programming without using a virtualenv may cause issues.